# PHP - Linked list "dynamic"

Tags: javascript, php

> I have a doubt with the linked list when reading from the database,
>   let me explain with an example.
>
> Example database:
>
> ```
> Country | City
> USA     | New York
> USA     | Washington
> USA     | Dallas
> USA     | LA
> SPAIN   | Madrid
> SPAIN   | Barcelona
> UK      | London
> UK      | Birmingham
> UK      | Liverpool
> ```
>
> HTML: 2 selects, for this example, the first is the country, and the
>   seconds are the country's cities. My doubt is if I can check
>   everything dynamically for example with:
>
> PHP Function 1
>
> ```
> $statement = $conexion->prepare("Select distinct Country from database");     $statement->execute();  $result1 =
> ```
>
> $statement->fetchAll(); Function 2 (recieve $country)
>
> ```
> enter code here
> $statement = $conexion->prepare("Select city from database where country = :country");    $statement->execute(array(":country" =>
> ```
>
> $country));   $result2 = $statement->fetchAll();
>
> 1º Idea: As the database will not be edited, the first idea is getting
>   all the options in a different variable, for example, $country and
>   $cityUSA, $citySPAIN and $cityUK, and load it when needed.
>
> 2º Idea: I want to load the required cities into the option when I
>   clicked in the first option, the PHP variable takes the value and
>   makes only 1 statement, but I don't have an idea how, because PHP only
>   takes GET and POST options.
>
> Sorry for my English and thank you, everyone!

The REAL DATA are the next:
Table PROJECT

```
c_project_id | d_name | d_description | n_budget | d_state
      1      |  Test  |  Test Project |    100   |  Open
      2      |  Web   |    Web APP    |   3000   |  Open
      3      | C Test |Closed Project |    100   | Closed
      4      | Certif.| Certificates  |   2500   |  Open
```

Table Categories (conected with table project)

```
c_category_id | d_name | d_description | c_project_id
     1        | General| General cat   |      1
     2        | Test   | Test cat      |      1
     3        | General| General cat   |      2
     4        | General| General cat   |      3
     5        | Nothing| Nothing cat   |      3
     6        |Program | Programming   |      2
...
```

I want a SELECT in html that takes the project name, I take it with:
PHP

```
$statement2 = $conexion->prepare("SELECT c_project_id, d_name FROM project WHERE d_state= 'Open'");
$statement2->execute();
$resultado2 = $statement2->fetchAll();
```

and a PHP foreach in the HTML code, this works and I put the next data.

```
<option value=<?php echo $res['c_project_id'] ?>><?php echo $res['d_name'] ?></option>
```

Now I want: When I "click" in the first select, the second select make the statement like that

```
$statement2 = $conexion->prepare("SELECT c_category_id, d_name FROM category WHERE c_project_id = :id");
```

But I don't know how to make this without submit the FORM with $_GET or $_POST and do it dinamycally.
I hope now I explained better.

Comment: 1. Normalize your database, 2. JavaScript/AJAX. This question, as it stands, lacks however a clear enough question to precisely answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database. This means splitting the tables into two, one for the country, one for the cities.

Give your countries an primary key column that is unique (and probably auto increment).

```
CountryId | CountryTag | CountryName
        1 | USA        | United States of America
        2 | ESP        | Spain
        3 | UK         | United Kingdom
```

Then create a Many-to-Many table with countries and cities, where the `CountryId` is a foreign key referring to your country table.

```
CountryId | CityName
        1 | New York
        1 | Washington
        1 | Dallas
        1 | Los Angeles
        2 | Madrid
        2 | Barcelona
        3 | London
        3 | Birmingham
        3 | Liverpool
```

Now you can construct a domain model with two queries:

```
$countries = array();
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries");
$statement->execute();
while ($row = = $statement->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $countries[$row['CountryId']] = $row;
    $countries[$row['CountryId']]['cities'] = array();
}

$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM cities");
$statement->execute();
while ($row = = $statement->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $countries[$row['CountryId']]['cities'][] = $row;
}
```

You can also do this in one Query if you utilize `JOIN`.

You now have this array:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["CountryId"]=>
    int(1)
    ["CountryTag"]=>
    string(3) "USA"
    ["CountryName"]=>
    string(24) "United States of America"
    ["cities"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "New York"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "Washington"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "Dallas"
      [3]=>
      string(11) "Los Angeles"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["CountryId"]=>
    int(2)
    ["CountryTag"]=>
    string(3) "ESP"
    ["CountryName"]=>
    string(5) "Spain"
    ["cities"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Madrid"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "Barcelona"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["CountryId"]=>
    int(3)
    ["CountryTag"]=>
    string(2) "UK"
    ["CountryName"]=>
    string(14) "United Kingdom"
    ["cities"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "London"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "Liverpool"
    }
  }
}
```

You can now loop over this however you want, it is indexed by `CountryId` and holds the name of the country and the cities within the country in it.

> 1º Idea: As the database will not be edited, the first idea is getting all the options in different variable, for example $country and $cityUSA, $citySPAIN and $cityUK, and load it when needed.

Then why bother with a database at all? you a config file that can be edited to alter the variables. Why `$cityUSA`, `$citySPAIN` ? `$cities['spain']`, `$cities['USA']` works just as well, but you do not have to hard-code the countries in your code.

> 2º Idea: I want to load the required cities into the option when I clicked in the first option, the PHP variable takes the value and make only 1 statement, but I don't have idea how, because PHP only takes GET and POST options.

With the above, you can either create option groups in a select, or output it into the site source as JSON to dynamically alter the select with JavaScript. or you load the cities via AJAX.

Working snippet:

```js
var countries = {"1":{"CountryId":1,"CountryTag":"USA","CountryName":"United States of America","cities":["New York","Washington","Dallas","Los Angeles"]},"2":{"CountryId":2,"CountryTag":"ESP","CountryName":"Spain","cities":["Madrid","Barcelona"]},"3":{"CountryId":3,"CountryTag":"UK","CountryName":"United Kingdom","cities":["London","Liverpool"]}};

var country_select = document.getElementById('countries');
var city_select = document.getElementById('cities');

// react to changes in the country select
country_select.onchange = function() {
    var elem = (typeof this.selectedIndex === "undefined" ? window.event.srcElement : this);
    var value = elem.value || elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    
    // empty cities select
    city_select.innerHTML = '';
    
    // populate with the correct cities;
    var country = countries[value];
   country['cities'].forEach(function(element) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.value = element;
     option.text = element;
     city_select.appendChild(option);
   });  
}
```

```html
<select id="countries">
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">Spain</option>
<option value="3">UK</option>
</select>

<select id="cities">
<option value="New York">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="Washington">Washington</option>
<option value="Dallas">Dallas</option>
<option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll EDIT the question with the real data to be more concrete, under the first question with "irreal" data. I didn't want to put the real data because I don't want you think that you are "doing my work" and I prefered an example, but I think this will be better.

Comment: @nasito90 My answer works perfectly for your "real data" as well. Furthermore you can easily adapt it to make the call via AJAX.

Comment: Sorry for bother you again.
I finally decided to do it with AJAX (I think is the best option), but I have some trouble because the html don't get the echos from the PHP, but I can't put it in the comment, should I put it under the primary post, a new post in this thread or a new thread?


I know the problem is that because the AJAX send correctly the data, and php recieve it (if I change some, a warning appear), but when I make the echo "<option>...</option>", the HTML file doesn't read it, and it appear in blank

Thank you

Comment: @nasito90 I have not understood a single thing of what you are saying. try to describe your problem as succinctly as possible. Where do the posts and threads come from?

Comment: Sorry, I maybe use de "pure translation" from spanish, I asked about writing my "problem with AJAX" related to this in a new question, or like an answer to this question, or below the principal post

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask a new question. And try to include an [mcve].